Please check your firewall rules and network connection then try again. Error Code: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
Github Copilot in VS Code was working fine VS code but getting this error now, whenever I am trying to enter any prompt to copilot.
"Please check your firewall rules and network connection then try again. Error Code: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED."


If anyone else facing this issue -
"Please check your firewall rules and network connection then try again. Error Code: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED." in VS Code
I have got it fixed in my system by adding this settings in VSCode
"github.copilot.advanced": {
        "debug.useNodeFetcher": true
    }
} 

Restart the editor after updating this setting.
